# Docker container can't connect to a Golang Echo Server running on host machine

Tags: docker, go, go-echo

I have a Golang Echo Server running on port 5050 using windows WSL. I can talk to the server perfectly fine from browser and through curl in a WSL terminal.

```golang
    // Start server
    go func() {
        e.Logger.Info("server starting on port: ", port)
        if err := e.Start("0.0.0.0:" + port); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Error("server error : ", err)
            e.Logger.Fatal("shutting down the server")
        }
    }()
```

But when I spin a docker container `docker run --rm -it curlimages/curl:7.86.0 /bin/sh` and do `curl http://host.docker.internal:5050/` I get error message saying can't connect.

I have already tried to manipulate the docker container through network="host" etc, but I don't think the issue is with docker container, because the same container can talk to a flask API running on port 5000 (the flask server is running in a container that is mapping 5000:5000, this is different than echo server which is running directly on the host machine)

Comment: curlimages can't get the wsl's network by `host.docker.internal`, you can get the wsl's ip, and `curl http://$(wsl's ip):5050/`

Comment: @Para then why does it connect to flask API using host.docker.internal

Comment: flask expot 5050 to the host machine where docker running,  if curl run in host machine, it connect

Comment: The curl is running in the same container and can talk to flask but not echo.